# ERROR : single row subquery returns how many rows when using case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM My_table
WHERE type_id IN 
CASE WHEN :P1_type IS NULL THEN (SELECT id FROM type)
ELSE (:P1_type)
END
```

when i try runing it i get this error:
`ORA-01427: Subquery returns more than one row` 
i thought my query is not correct so i tried this

```
SELECT * FROM My_table
WHERE type_id IN (SELECT id FROM type)
```

this time it worked perfectly which means (in my opinion) that the case statement doesn't work normally with queries that return more than one row. so is there a solution to this problem or do i have to find something other than CASE statement to work with.
also i wanted to use PL/SQL but i can't because this query will be used in an APEX application and PL\SQL in this case is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **NULL** and **NOT NULL** cases might be combined through use of [`NVL2()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2049.htm#OLADM625) function such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE type_id IN ( SELECT NVL2(:p1_type,:p1_type,id) FROM type )
```

Alternatively a **LEFT JOIN** might be used along with `NVL2()` again such as

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.*
  FROM my_table m
  LEFT JOIN type 
    ON type_id = NVL2(:p1_type,:p1_type,id)
 WHERE id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not how `CASE` expressions (yes, **expressions**, not *statements*) work. They can only be used for scalar values, not sets.

But you don't need `CASE`, just use Boolean operators.

```
SELECT *
       FROM my_table
       WHERE :p1_type IS NULL
             AND type_id IN (SELECT id
                                    FROM type)
              OR :p1_type IS NOT NULL
                 AND type_id = :p1_type;
```

Comment: Are you sure it'll work properly? When I see `OR` and no parenthesis, I suspect way too many *unwanted* values to be returned.

Comment: @Littlefoot: `AND` takes precedence before `OR`, so parenthesis aren't needed.

Comment: OK then, even better.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM My_table t
WHERE t.type_id = :P1_type OR
      (:P1_type IS NULL AND
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM type WHERE t.id = type.id)
      );
```

Your version doesn't work because `CASE` is an expression in SQL that returns a single value, not a list.  Hence, it doesn't make sense to use it with `IN`.

Note:  It seems very strange to me that something called `type_id` would *not* refer to `type.id`.  If that is the case,  then `NULL` would seem to mean "all rows" and the subquery is not necessary:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM My_table t
WHERE t.type_id = :P1_type OR :P1_type IS NULL;
```